# Arduino Global Variables

Tags: arduino

I recently just tried to upload this code to my Arduino Uno:

https://pastebin.com/Vx3tY9Mr

And then got this error when uploading the sketch to my Arduino Uno AVR Board.
Here is the error message:

```
Sketch uses 18826 bytes (58%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 5679 bytes (277%) of dynamic memory, leaving -3631 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
Not enough memory; see http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#size for tips on reducing your footprint.
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

Edit - I know what the error means, I just don't know how to fix it

Comment: Try using the F Macro on all those constant strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all the strings making up your web page are being put into RAM, which is being called "global variables" by the Arduino IDE.

I think there is a macro to put them into flash instead. As a test, try putting a few strings into `F("some html here")` and see if the "global" size decreases a little.

Also, why not make one giant string in ROM?